# One to One relation is not working in the Nop Commerce Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, nopcommerce

I am working with nop Commerce 2.30. I create a table in the nopCommerce db and set the

1:1 relation in an another table.

my table is Agenda. Please see my table structure.

[image]

Please see the database diagram.

[image]

BaseEntity class

```
 /// <summary>
/// Base class for entities
/// </summary>
public abstract partial class BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the entity identifier
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
```

Please see my Model. I add a new property Id in my Agenda class. But it's

shown a warning message this property is alredy exists it's base class.

namespace Nop.Core.Domain.Agendas

{

```
public partial class Agenda : BaseEntity

{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Days> Days { get; set; }
}
```

}

Mapping

> `public partial class AgendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration

```
{

    public AgendaMap()
    {

        this.ToTable("Agenda");

        this.HasKey(a => a.Id);
    }
}`
```

Then i try to insert in the Agenda table.

[image]

I get this error message

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked throug debug that the conferenceId isn't null?

Comment: No it's not null. I give the conferenceId is 52.But please see the model class of agenda. Id property is not defined. Id property is get from the BaseEntity class. not in the Agenda model. I try to insert same Id of product table in to the agenda Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you diagram, it looks like you have do not have a key in your Agenda table design, whereas you set it as key in your code. Try the following:

1. In your DB table design, set Id as Primary Key, making sure it is set to auto-increment.
2. Add a new field named 'ProductId', and this is the key that should be linked to the Id field of Product table.
3. Update your code accordingly. :)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. But I want to a One-to-One relation

Comment: Don't define Id in your Agenda class, it already gets that from BaseEntity.  If you want to link it to Product then you should use a ProductId in addition to the Agenda's own Id.  It will still be 1-1.